# C++ Calling a function before base-class initialization in the initialization list

Tags: c++, constructor

## The Scenario:

In a project, I have `class B` which is derived from `class A`, where `class A` has an inaccessible default constructor.

`Class B` is set up as follows:

```
class B : public A
{
private:
    void SetupFunction() { /*Crucial code*/ }
public:
    B() : A(Value) {}
}
```

Supposing it is crucial for `SetupFunction()` to be called during initialization **before** the `A(Value)` constructor, how would I go about achieving this? Is it possible?

I'm using `Code::Blocks 13.12` on Windows 7

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could make `SetupFunction()` return the value that's then passed to initialise `A`, e.g:

```
class B : public A
{
private:
    int SetupFunction() { /*Crucial code*/ return Value; }
public:
    B() : A(SetupFunction()) {}
}
```

Or use the comma operator if you don't want to change `SetupFunction()`:

```
class B : public A
{
private:
    void SetupFunction() { /*Crucial code*/ }
public:
    B() : A((SetupFunction(), Value)) {}
}
```

Comment: Now what if you want to invoke `A`'s default constructor?

Comment: @Brian: *where class A has an inaccessible default constructor*

Comment: @Brian, I can't for the life of me find the SO question, but you can make a base class that does `SetupFunction`in its constructor and put that one first in the inheritance list.

Comment: I wish I could vote SUPER USEFUL +10. Side question: Is this a good practice? Is this safe?