# Can I reuse the return value of a function multiple times in a parent constructor?

Tags: c++, function, caching, constructor, return-value

Similar to this question, but enough different that I don't think it's a duplicate:
[C++ Calling a function before base-class initialization in the initialization list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33338718/3491308)

---

I have this constructor:

```
EditorGrid::EditorGrid(int width, int height) :
    Grid(width  ,   //workingWidth
         height ,   //workingHeight
         (SettingsApp::getInstance(0)->iconSize + SettingsApp::getInstance(0)->iconSpace                                         )  ,   //pitchWidth
         (SettingsApp::getInstance(0)->iconSize + SettingsApp::getInstance(0)->iconSpace + SettingsApp::getInstance(0)->iconLabel)      //pitchHeight
         )
{
    //EditorGrid-specific setup
}
```

It works, but it looks ugly to me to call `SettingsApp::getInstance(0)` so many times when I know it's going to return the same thing every time.  Can I call it once and just reuse that value in this context?
(in this case, a pointer to a `SettingsApp` object)

(The reason it's structured like this is because different children of `Grid` have different equations for `pitchWidth` and `pitchHeight`, and I want to keep the singleton idea of implicitly using the same object everywhere without actually passing it.)

Comment: `static inline int getDefaultPitchWidth()`? That's usually how one handles repetitive code.

Comment: @StoryTeller Does `inline` still make sense in the code?

Comment: @EdgarRokyan - Define "makes sense"

Comment: @StoryTeller modern compilers inline functions automatically with appropriate optimisations turned on. I guess `inline` is obsolete now.

Comment: @EdgarRokyan - It's not. It's very much required as a linkage specification. That's why every function provided inside the class definition is implicitly also `inline`.

Comment: The following question is related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17375114/c-temporary-variables-in-initilization-list.

Comment: @Alexey That's basically bolov's answer, but less clear.

Comment: @AaronD, I understand ) I've just lost the link to tie them, helping searchers and search engines to find more relevant information more easily.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ temporary variables in initilization list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17375114/c-temporary-variables-in-initilization-list)

Comment: @underscore_d Technically, it probably is, but the other one is not clear enough in either the question or the answer for me to recognize it as such if I were to look at it on my own.  It's mostly a formatting issue; the other code looks like a mess to me.  I try to use whitespace as part of my self-documentation, which I think works wonders being a graphical thinker, and the other question just doesn't.

Comment: @AaronD Yeah, formatting is very important. For example, never underestimate the power of a well-placed double newline to help the mind change topics! (I also seem to be rare in preferring spaces between nested brackets of various kinds...) And looking at it again, the code in that question is quite horribly formatted, so I can see why that'd make you less likely to consider it. Well, no worries, the mods rejected my flag! :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a (possibly private) ctor having as argument the value you want to compute only once and delegate to it:

```
EditorGrid::EditorGrid(int width, int height, /*your_type*/& instance_0) :
    Grid(width, height,
         instance_0.iconSize + instance_0.iconSpace,
         instance_0.iconSize + instance_0.iconSpace + instance_0.iconLabel
{
    //EditorGrid-specific setup
}

EditorGrid::EditorGrid(int width, int height) :
    EditorGrid(width, height, *SettingsApp::getInstance(0))
{
}
```

Comment: +1 That solves the immediate problem, but is there a way to do this without adding a private ctor?  If not, I'll probably do it this way.

Comment: @AaronD why wouldn't you want to add a ctor? This is the idiomatic way, and I don't see any downside to it. If there is another way I don't know about it and can't think of it.

Comment: Mostly for styling.  It's not a huge deal; it just looks a bit like `void foo() {bar();}`

Comment: @AaronD no, it looks like `std::vector<string> split(const std::string& str, char split_char) { return split(str, [=](char c) { return c == split_char; });}` where you have multiple overloads all doing the same thing, but with different arguments: you can specify the split either by a `char`, a collection of chars (e.g. `std::string`) or a functor. So you implement the logic in the most generic overload and have all other overloads just call that one. Just a random example to show you it is not strange at all.

Comment: Hmm.  Okay, I guess that makes sense.  I'll wait a day or so to see what else shows up, but this looks like a good answer.

Comment: It's quite common to have to massage constructor arguments to get where you need to be. But just for fun, here's another way to do it: `EditorGrid(int width, int height, const /*your_type*/& instance_0 = *SettingsApp::getInstance(0));` I hope you hate this approach,.

Comment: @PeteBecker Why should I hate it?  It looks like exactly what I wanted...oh, wait...that's an optional argument with a default value.  I've been bitten by that before: the code compiles just fine, but it behaves weird because the default value of an unprovided optional argument did something different from what I expected.  So I like my arguments to be either required or not even available.  So yes, after thinking about it a bit, I think I *will* reject it.  :-)